# form based authentication Create User method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

I am new to Membership and role provider by asp.net

All the articles I saw are using static method of Membership calss (CreateUser method) to create a new user. I also want to use it but my form has some custom fields to be added to Users table. How I should manage it ? deals with this data sepraetly ? If you suggest that it will have 2 calls to database. Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a overload for `CreateUser` method in your custom membership provider by adding additional parameters

```
public MembershipUser CreateUser(
    string username,
    string password,
    string email,
    string passwordQuestion,
    string passwordAnswer,
    bool isApproved,
    Object providerUserKey,
    DateTime birthday,
    out MembershipCreateStatus status
)
```

Then in your page you can call it by

```
((CustomMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).CreateUser(/*parameters to your custom method*/)
```